# JQuery - select text between <br> s and wrap in <span>

Tags: jquery

I know that this:

```
$("#id").html().split("<br>")[1];
```

gets 'Song name' from the HTML below.

**How do I then wrap 'Song name' in a < span > in the HTML?**

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="id">
  252. 
  <br>
  Song name
  <br>
  — Song Title
</a>
```

**SOLVED!**

See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I guess `wrapInner`function is what you are looking for

https://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, this isn't working, see comments in 'stianly's answer

Answer (score 0):

I can see the logic in the other answers but neither of them worked. Seems as though I couldn't put anything after

```
$("#id").html().split("<br>")[1]
```

...without it being deemed 'not a function' in console.

In the end I achieved what I wanted to by storing various chunks of code in variables and splicing them together e.g.

```
var middleLineOfTitle = data.response.posts[i].title.split("<br />")[1];
var middleLineOfTitleWrapped = "<span class='middleLineOfPostNameClass'>" + middleLineOfTitle + "</span>";
var entireTitle = data.response.posts[i].title.replace(middleLineOfTitle, middleLineOfTitleWrapped);

$('#recent-posts').append('<li><a href="' + data.response.posts[i].post_url +'"> ' + entireTitle + '</li>');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("#id").html().split("<br>")[1].prepend("<span>").append("</span>");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. This isn't working, console says it's not a valid function. Same when I try `$("#middleLineOfPostName").html().split("<br>")[1].wrapInner( "<span class='middleLineOfPostNameClass'></span>");`

Comment: It's as if you can't put anything on the end of: `$("#middleLineOfPostName").html().split("<br>")[1]`